# Cleared local schema.rb. Will it affect when I push to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I had delete and regenerate my db schema file. Will it delete everything on my Heroku app? If so, how do I roll back?

Comment: Did you just delete schema.rb or deleted migration files?

Comment: Just schema.rb @dmtri.com

Comment: You may be able to re-populate the schema.rb by running rake db:migrate locally, but I would just revert to a previous Git commit. If you wrote a significant amount of code since then, just copy it onto another file and then paste it back after the hard reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run heroku rake db:migrate it will migrate your migration files, not your schema.rb. If you deleted the migration files, you should do a hard reset to a prior Git commit (assuming you're using Git). This will revert you to the prior commit and erase all changes.

```
git reset --hard "FIRST 7 DIGITS OF PREVIOUS GIT COMMIT GO HERE"
```

Comment: The schema.db is just a representation of your database since the previous migration. I'm not sure if you've made any migrations since deleting the schema.rb file, probably not since there's still no schema.rb and I think it would re-appear if you did. However, reverting to the previous Git commit is probably the best choice. I would run rake db:migrate after reverting and check the schema.rb to make sure its inline with whatever your last migration was. This can be checked by looking at the version number on the 1st line of the schema.rb after the comments, make sure it matches last migration